# Gson ArrayList<different Objsct>

Tags: java, android

```
   //output 

    String outStr = "";
    ArrayList<DateItemVO> dateItem= dateItemDAO.findItemSeller(memberInteger);
    ArrayList<Member> member= new ArrayList<Member>();
    ArrayList<Pet> pet= new ArrayList<Pet>();
    ArrayList<Restaurant> restaurant= new ArrayList<Restaurant>();
    OrderVOAll orderVO = new OrderVOAll(dateItem,member,pet,restaurant);
    Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
    outStr = gson.toJson(orderVO);
    rp.setContentType(text/html; charset=UTF-8);
    PrintWriter out = rp.getWriter();
    out.println(outStr);
```

//input

```
    jsonIn = getRemoteImage(url, jsonObject.toString());
     private String getRemoteImage(String url, String jsonOut) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder jsonIn = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true); // allow inputs
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // allow outputs
    connection.setUseCaches(false); // do not use a cached copy
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
    bw.write(jsonOut);
    Log.d(TAG, "jsonOut: " + jsonOut);
    bw.close();

    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    if (responseCode == 200) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine())!=null){
            jsonIn.append(line);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "jsonInqq: " + jsonIn);
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "response code: " + responseCode);
    }
    connection.disconnect();
    return jsonIn.toString();
}
    Gson gson=  new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();
    return gson.fromJson(jsonIn,OrderVOAll.class);
```

the other side when i catch the json i got an errer.i can got the message from db ,but i dont know the reason why i got the msgm

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

thanks for help

Comment: Can you put an example of what jsonIn has inside?

Comment: has updated ,thx

Comment: What is the output in here:  Log.d(TAG, "jsonInqq: " + jsonIn); ?

Comment: i have solved the problem,thx
cus the Servlet doGet method have sent more word in my jsonIn, make the Gson wrong .thank for ur help!!